# Regematch if, and, and date combined forumula

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need help trying to figure out a combination google sheets formula

```
If 
    Cell B5 contains "Rct"
And
    today's date is 30 days after the date defined in cell C5
And
    if Cell D5 and D6 both says "2 weeks ago" or "1 week ago" or contains the words "day" "hour" or "minute"
```

(not sure if possible but instead of the all those words could if be if the text in cell D5 and D6 are the color "green" and or "Yellow")

```
Then
    Cell H5 will say "Y" if the above conditions are met or "N" if they aren't
```

The following formula works for what I asked above

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B5:B29), "rct"))*
             (TODAY()>C5:C29+30)*
             (REGEXMATCH(LOWER(D5:D29), "2 weeks ago|1 week ago|day|hour|minute"))*
             (REGEXMATCH(LOWER(E5:E29), "2 weeks ago|1 week ago|day|hour|minute")), 
             "Y", "N"))
```

However I am new to doing this coding stuff on the google sheets and I though I could add to that formula myself without troubling someone else.

Is there any way to add to that formula so that

```
If
    Cell B5:B28 contains "cdt"
and
    today's date is 60 days after the date defined in cell F5:F29
And
   if Cell D5 and D6 both says "2 weeks ago" or "1 week ago" or contains the words "day" "hour" or "minute"
Then
    Cell H5 will say "Y" if the above conditions are met or "N" if they aren't
```

as well as

```
If
   Cell B5:B28 contains "pvt"
and
   today's date is 90 days after the date defined in cell F5:F29
And
   if Cell D5 and D6 both says "2 weeks ago" or "1 week ago" or contains the words "day" "hour" or "minute"
Then
    Cell H5 will say "Y" if the above conditions are met or "N" if they aren't
```

[image: Picture of my google sheet]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in **H5**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B5:B), "rct"))*
                 (TODAY()>C5:C+30)*
                 (REGEXMATCH(LOWER(D5:D), "2 weeks ago|1 week ago|day|hour|minute"))*
                 (REGEXMATCH(LOWER(E5:E), "2 weeks ago|1 week ago|day|hour|minute")), 
                 "Y", "N"))
```

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B5:B), "rct"))*(TODAY()>C5:C+30))+
                  ((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B5:B), "cdt"))*(TODAY()>C5:C+60))+
                  ((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B5:B), "pvt"))*(TODAY()>C5:C+90)))*
                   (REGEXMATCH(LOWER(D5:D), "2 weeks ago|1 week ago|day|hour|minute"))*
                   (REGEXMATCH(LOWER(E5:E), "2 weeks ago|1 week ago|day|hour|minute")),
                   "Y", "N"))
```